# CSS Calc ios8 not working

Tags: css, ios8, css-calc

Hy! I'm really confused about this bug! I have a table, where 1 columns width is created dynamically with following css:

```
width: calc(100% - 160px);
```

The 160px are all other columns together, so the rest of the possible device width is for this calculated column! This works fine under ios7 but since ios8 it looks like that the calc function does nothing???